# ignorar na chamada da função se vazio

Tags: python, python-3.x

suponha-se que vou alimentar uma função com uma tuple:

```
a = ['c:/', 'd:/', 'x:/', 'y:/']
b = ['c:/data', 'd:/data']
funcao((a, b))
```

porem caso tenha uma list que esteja vazia gostaria que fosse ignorada exemplo:

```
funcao((se_vazio_ignore(a), se_vazio_ignore(b)))
```

é possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi, algo assim já resolve:

```
if len(a) > 0 and len(b) > 0:
    funcao((a, b))
```

---

**EDIT**

Na verdade você também precisa verificar se algum dos elementos não está nulo:

```
if len(a) > 0 and len(b) > 0 and all(e != '' for e in a) and all(e != '' for e in b):
    funcao((a, b))
```

Comment: então não resolveu pois uma list vazia como lista = [''] se vc usar len(lista) ira te retornar o tamanho de 1.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Em Python uma lista vazia jpá tem valor booleano falso - não precisa escrever `if len(a) > 0 ` somente `if a`

Answer (score 1):

Se umalista estiver vazia, e a função for usar os elementos da lista, você não precisa fazer and - o corpo do `for` que for usar a lista simplesmente não será executado.

```
def funcao(x):
   for lista in x:
       for elemento in lista:
           # fazer coisas

funcao((a, b))
```

Pronto, no caso de "a" ser uma lista vazia o `for`interno simplesmente não será executado.

Em outras situações você pode quere rpassar algum outro valor no caso de sua variável ser uma lista vazia, ou None, ou outro valor falso. Nesse caso, você pode usar o "short circuit" do operador `or` - da mesma forma que é usaodo em lignuagens com a sintaxe derivada de C (que usam `||` como operador de "or").

Vamos supor que sua variável "a" ou 'b" pudessem ter o valor `None`. Nesse caso, elas não poderiam ser usadas diretamente no `for`: daria um erro dizendo que `None` não é interável :

```
funcao((a or [], b or []))
```

(para chamr a mesma função acima, garantindo que cada um dos elementos é iterável).